# Python argparse: "multiple multiples" of arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to use argparse to receive an arbitrary number of *sets* of positional arguments on the command line.  For example:

```
myapp.py show 1
```

The `show` parameter is an "operation" and the `1` is an "operand".

I want to be able to accept *multiple* sets of operations and operands:

```
myapp.py show 1 test 2 write 3
```

I know I can add an argument with a `nargs` parameter of `N` as the final argument to allow an arbitrary number of repeats of that argument. I'm looking to do the same but with more than one argument per repeat.

In this example:

```
myapp.py show 1 test
```

should be invalid, because each operation must come with an operand.

Also, assuming all operands are integers and all operators are strings:

```
myapp.py 1 show 2 test
```

should fail, or at least be detectable in code so I can cause failure, because the operator must come first.

I also might need more than two "parameters" per repeated set of arguments in a different project, like:

```
myapp.py test 1 outputFile.dat write 2 writeFile.dat
```

Can this be done?

Comment: How would you feel about having a `--` in front of those operands?  `myapp.py --show 1 --test 2`

Comment: I could do that but it wouldn't work for the second example where I need two operands per operation.

Comment: how about using [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/arguments/#variadic-arguments)?

Comment: @fdmillion -- Sorry, I said operands and meant operators.  Why wouldn't it work if you had 2 operands for a given operator?  `myapp.py --show 1 --test 1 2 --other 1`.  As long as each operator knows how many operands it takes ... Also, do you expect the operators to be given more than once?  Does their order matter?

Comment: This isn't a good fit with `argparse`.  Just split `sys.argv[1:]` into the required mix of pairs or triplets.

Comment: Who or what determines which operation takes one argument v. two.

Comment: `argparse` follows a POSIX style of parsing, multiple defined flagged arguments (with - or --) and some positionals.  You want something quite different.  Flags without the identifying prefix and definition, or a free form key/value pairing.. It's a very different logic.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the suggest in the comments given by @mgilson, here's an example where the operations are prefixed with `--`, this seems to work:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs=2)
...
>>> parser.add_argument('--bar', nargs=2)
...
>>> args = parser.parse_args(('--foo', '1', 'out.dat', '--bar', '2', 'out.dat'))
>>> args
Namespace(bar=['2', 'out.dat'], foo=['1', 'out.dat'])
```

You could then do additional parsing on each sub element with another argparser:

```
>>> fooparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> fooparser.add_argument('num', type=int)
...
>>> fooparser.add_argument('fname')
...
>>> fooparser.parse_args(args.foo)
Namespace(fname='out.dat', num=1)
```

Of course, if the second argparser failed you'd get a quite strange error message, so you may want to manually parse each 2-arg yourself and produce your own error messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
argv=sys.argv[1:]
adict = {k:int(v) for k,v in zip(argv[::2], argv[1::2])}
```

In words - collect pairs of strings from the command line in a dictionary. This would also work with the undifferentiated list strings from a `nargs='*'` positional or `extras` from `parse_known_args`.  Error checking/ trapping is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

```
In [41]: argv='myapp.py show 1 test 2 write 3'.split()
In [42]: argv=argv[1:]
In [43]: adict = {k:int(v) for k,v in zip(argv[::2], argv[1::2])}
In [44]: adict
Out[44]: {'show': 1, 'test': 2, 'write': 3}
```

Or a generator approach may give you more control over the splitting and parsing:

```
def gen(alist):
    it = iter(alist)
    while True:
        yield (next(it),int(next(it)))
In [68]: {k:v for k,v in gen(argv)}
Out[68]: {'show': 1, 'test': 2, 'write': 3}
```